# Unable to make a property by @Input to child element in angular 2?

Tags: angular

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:   'login-form',
    templateUrl:    '../app/templates/login-form.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent{

    ifTrue: boolean = true;
}
```

**login-form.component.html**

```
<h1>Login form</h1>
<detail-form [namez]='ifTrue'>Loding...</detail-form>
```

**detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector:   'detail-form',
    templateUrl:    '../templates/add-user.component.html'
})
export class DetComponent implements OnInit{
    myName = 'Sai';
    Ram = 'RamS';
    @Input()
    namez;
}
```

**add-user.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="namez">
    <input #in [value]="Ram"/>
</div>
```

in the `add-user.component.html` the input value will be calculated from `Ram` expression from `detail.component.ts`. If I make the same input property `[value]` to `[some_var]` I need to add `@Input()` for `some_var` some where in the application. I did it for `[namez]` that is used in `login-form.component.html`. But I am unable to add for some_var. Please help me to solve this. How can I add @Input for childs? I am unable to add it in `detail.component.ts` as I did earlier. In a word, I want to do the same thing to `[some_var]`(add-user.component.html) as `[namez]`(login-form.component.html)